# How to connect to wireless network programmatically in iOS swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, wifi, wifimanager

I have been trying to connect to wireless network with a code below:
`

```
@IBAction func buttonCon(_ sender: Any){
        
        
        print("button connect clicked")
        
        let NetWifi = NEHotspotConfiguration(
                            ssid: "NetworkName",
                            passphrase: "12345678",
                            isWEP: false
                        )
    
        
        //deleting...
        NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.getConfiguredSSIDs { (NetWifi) in
            NetWifi.forEach { NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.removeConfiguration(forSSID: $0) }
            // ... from here you can use your usual approach to autoconnect to your network
        }
        
        print("deleting...")
        sleep(5)
        
        
        //Connect to Internet
        NetWifi.joinOnce = true
        print("connection")
        
        /*NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(NetWifi) { error in
            // Handle error or success
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }
         */
        
        NEHotspotConfigurationManager.shared.apply(NetWifi) { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                
                if error?.localizedDescription == "already associated." {
                    print("Connected")
                }
                //an error occurred
                print("error is: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                print("error occurred")
            }
            else {
                print("connected!")
                //success
            }
        }
```

`

This is the output of the error that I'm getting:

```
2022-11-28 15:51:52.679102-0500 Testing[890:76198] 10.1.0 - [GULReachability][I-REA902003] Monitoring the network status
button connect clicked
deleting...
2022-11-28 15:51:53.858789-0500 Testing[890:76198] [] Failed to send a 9 message to nehelper: <dictionary: 0x217d6fe90> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x217d70028> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}
2022-11-28 15:51:53.858938-0500 Testing[890:76198] [] NEHotspotConfigurationHelper failed to communicate to helper server.
connection
sleep-5
2022-11-28 15:51:58.862066-0500 Testing[890:76200] [] Failed to send a 9 message to nehelper: <dictionary: 0x217d6fe90> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x217d70028> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}
2022-11-28 15:51:58.862191-0500 Testing[890:76200] [] NEHotspotConfigurationHelper failed to communicate to helper server.
2022-11-28 15:51:59.039461-0500 Testing[890:76200] [connection] nw_connection_add_timestamp_locked_on_nw_queue [C1] Hit maximum timestamp count, will start dropping events
error is: Optional("internal error.")
error occurred
```

I've looked around on stackoverflow for related issues but, the majority of the posts are old and did not work. I also looked on apple's developer page and found similar results.
I am running iOS 15.0 and the previous posts were below that.
I am not sure what to do and I'm looking for help.